# split string in a column into two columns

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, split

In my dataframe I have a column of strings like:

```
**type**
game/design_game
game/art_game
design/product design 
fashion/accessories 
games/tabletop games 
art/digital art      
art/public art
```

And I want to split it into two from / like:

```
main_cat       subcat        
game           design_game        
game           art_game
```

I am applying split function:

```
   df.column.str.split('/',n=1, expand = True)
```

But I get only the main_cat column and not subcats

Also I tried alternatively:

```
 # new data frame with split value columns
 new = df["column"].str.split("/", n = 1, expand = True)

 # making separate first name column from new data frame
 df["subcat"]= new[1]

 # making separate last name column from new data frame
 df["main_cat"]= new[0]

 # df display
 df.head(2)
```

But get keyerror for new[1]

Comment: For me working correct.

Comment: Yes, It should have been, but not for me. Is there a way to check the reason why?

Comment: Like any pythonic technique for string manipulation?

Comment: One idea - check if `/` by `df["column"].head().tolist()` ? And then try copy if no some another char `/` to `df["column"].str.split("copied char", n = 1, expand = True)`

Comment: Did you tried split it when reading DF ? Using parameter sep="/"?

Comment: My initial data contained a column as dictionaries. After spliting the dictionary into multiple columns I have this type of column. Can sep be used in this case?

Comment: Your code works fine with me.  Could you provide the exact cut and paste code ?  May be it's a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex with [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups). Thus you don't need to worry about missing data.

The first part `[^/]+` matches any string without `/`, then `.*` matches the rest of the string:

```
df['type'].str.extract('(?P<main_cat>[^/]+)/(?P<subcat>.*)')
```

output:

```
  main_cat          subcat
0     game     design_game
1     game        art_game
2   design  product design
3  fashion     accessories
4    games  tabletop games
5      art     digital art
6      art      public art
```

NB. if you expect to have lines with only a main_cat and want to catch it:

```
df['type'].str.extract('(?P<main_cat>[^/]+)/?(?P<subcat>.*)')
```

example if the last line was 'art' only:

```
  main_cat          subcat
6      art
```